# Setting the size of the background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, and currently am facing an issue with the background color size. Here's the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/p2lSC6RgS5#).

I want my gray background color's size in such a way that it's between the two red bars. Here's my HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-10 top-con">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">

        <div class="bar bar-first"> </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 dashfolio-profile-pic-connect-container">
      <!-- content here -->   

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 dashfolio-profile-name-container">
      <!-- content here -->    
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs right-bars">

        <div class="bar bar-sixth"> </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
top-con {
  background: gray;
  }

.bar {
   width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding: 0;
  }
```

I've tried to wrap the children of the `top-con` element in a seperate `wrap` class and tried to assign a color to it as shown here - [bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/5qFnLofCmI) , but this doesnt even display the color. Please help. The intended result is for the gray to be within the red bars. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should not apply `background-color` to `top-con`. Since it is also the container for the `red` background `<div>`. So apply the `background` for the `child` nodes, Instead of the parent node. Then coming to the your next question

> I've tried to wrap the children of the top-con element in a seperate wrap class and tried to assign

This is because there is not known height for the grey `<div>`. So assign the height separately. Refer the [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/d0oCU1K1m1)